# In a Makefile, is it possible to have a target be out of date iff another target is out of date?

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I want to write a rule that looks something like this:

```
foo.out: (out of date if foo.in is newer than foo.out.stamp)
    # update foo.out if and only if the new foo.out has different contents
    # than the old foo.out (a change to foo.in may or may not change foo.out)
    && touch foo.out.stamp
```

I can't do this:

```
foo.out.stamp: foo.in
    # update foo.out if and only if the new foo.out has different contents
    # than the old foo.out (a change to foo.in may or may not change foo.out)
    && touch foo.out.stamp

foo.out: foo.out.stamp
```

Because if `foo.in` changes, but the recipe for `foo.out.stamp` does not change `foo.out`, `make` will always view `foo.out` as out of date.

Is there any way to write this kind of rule?

Edit: Explanation of why I don't unconditionally touch `foo.out`:

I am working with Vala. The Vala compilation process looks something like this:

1. For each `.vala` file, generate a `.vapi` file (similar to a header file).
2. For each `.vala` file, generate a `.c` file (this requires the individual `.vala` file and *every* `.vapi` file to be given to the compiler)
3. Continue the typical `.c -> .o -> executable/library` process.

For steps #1 and #2, the Vala compiler only updates the `.vapi`/`.c` file if its contents have been changed. This is to prevent needless `.c -> .o` recompilation.

In makefile terms:

- A `.vapi` file is out of date if the `.vala` file has changed since the last time the Vala compiler regenerated the `.vapi` file (not the last time that the `.vapi` file was modified).
- A `.c` file is out of date if the `.vala` or *any* `.vapi` file has changed since the last time the Vala compiler regenerated the `.c` file (not the last time that the `.c` file was modified).

Comment: In your second example: Why don't you touch `foo.out` unconditionally (or, at least, if no error has occurred)?

Comment: Actually, I am facing similar issues in one of my projects. Currently I just live with it but I'd definitely like to see a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding a top-level rule that ensures the stamps are always up to do, and empty rules for the real output files:

```
all: %.out.stamp

%.out: ;
```

Technically that isn't exactly what I did, because I am not writing the Makefiles by hand (I am working with cmake). In CMake terms, I added a custom target that depends on all the `.vapi.stamp` and `.dep` (similar to a `.c.stamp`) files. The CMake target that builds the executable/library from the `.c` files depends on this target.

Answer (score 1):

There was a technique roughly equivalent to what you want used in Kernighan & Pike ['The UNIX Programming Environment'](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/upe/) (1984), used with Yacc grammars.

The Yacc source file might be `grammar.y`.  The default output files from Yacc were `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`.  Other files (notably the lexical analyzer) depend on the header, but the header doesn't often change even though the C code for the grammar (the actions) does.  So, it was sensible to ensure that the header used by the lexical analyzer was changed only if the header generated by Yacc was different.  The way of dealing with that was to have the lexical analyzer include `x.tab.h` (not `y.tab.h`), and to copy a new `y.tab.h` over the old `x.tab.h` only if there was a difference.

```
x.tab.h: y.tab.h
   -cmp -s x.tab.h y.tab.h || cp y.tab.h x.tab.h
```

This is harder to apply in your context because you don't seem to have control over the file names that you can use in the same way — the `filename.vala` file produces `filename.vapi` and `filename.c`, and other Vala source files needing the services of code in `filename.vala` will automatically include `filename.vapi`.

---

You say:

> In makefile terms:
>
> - A `.vapi` file is out of date if the `.vala` file has changed since the last time the Vala compiler regenerated the `.vapi` file (not the last time that the `.vapi` file was modified).
> - A `.c` file is out of date if the `.vala` or *any* `.vapi` file has changed since the last time the Vala compiler regenerated the `.c` file (not the last time that the `.c` file was modified).

The first rule is simply the normal source/object relationship:

```
%.vapi: %.vala
    $(VALAC) -h $*.vala
```

Where (I'm guessing) the `-h` option generates the header (`.vapi`) file from the Vala source, and the corresponding `-c` option generates the C source (`.c`) file.

The second rule is also a normal source/object relationship:

```
%.c: %.vala
    $(VALAC) -c $*.vala
```

This says that the `.c` file is regenerated from the `.vala` file if the `.vala` file is more recent than the `.c` file.
Additionally, the `.c` file depends on the `.vapi` files it includes:

```
file1.c:  file2.vapi file3.vapi file4.vapi ...
```

Comment: The key behavior of `valac` that makes the normal source/object relationship not work is this: running `$(VALAC) --fast-vapi=foo.vapi foo.vala` might not change the modification date of `foo.vapi`. `$(VALAC) -C foo.vala --use-fast-vapi=*.vapi` might not change the modification date of `foo.c`. So `foo.vapi`/`foo.c` remain perpetually out of date.

Comment: Ah, I may be misunderstanding again.  If the problem is 'might not change the modification date _and it should_', then a useful pattern might be `$(VALAC) --fast-vapi=$@ $< && touch $@`, which will ensure that $@ (=foo.vapi) is newer if the compilation is successful.  But perhaps you've tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following works for you:

```
foo.out.stamp: foo.in
    # if the new foo.out has different contents than the old foo.out
    update foo.out && touch foo.out.stamp
    #else
    touch -r foo.out foo.out.stamp

foo.out: foo.out.stamp
```

The second invocation of `touch` updates the time stamp of `foo.out.stamp` with that of `foo.out`. From the manpage:

> ```
> -r, --reference=FILE
>       use this file's times instead of current time
> ```

Comment: This does not work, because `foo.out` in the real makefile is `foo.c`, which must then be compiled to `foo.o`. This approach will cause unnecessary recompilation of `foo.c -> foo.o`.

Comment: @Matthew: Have you tried it? The `touch -r` will reset the timestamp of `foo.out` aka `foo.c` backward in time, thus causing no recompilation (just my guess...).

Comment: `touch -r foo.out foo.out.stamp` resets the timestamp of `foo.out.stamp` to that of `foo.out`, not the other way around. Neither order (`-r foo.out foo.out.stamp` or `-r foo.out.stamp foo.out`) works, for the reasons that I described in my original question. I did try both.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to match your description of the relationships between the `.vapa` and `.vali` files:

```
% cat Makefile
VFILES=A B

.PRECIOUS: $(VFILES:=.vapi)

%.vapi: %.vala
    touch $@

%.c: %.vala $(VFILES:=.vapi)
    echo "$^" >$@

%.o: %.c
    touch $@

all: A.o
% ls
A.vala      B.vala      Makefile
% make A.o
touch A.vapi
touch B.vapi
echo "A.vala A.vapi B.vapi" >A.c
touch A.o
rm A.c
% make B.o
echo "B.vala A.vapi B.vapi" >B.c
touch B.o
rm B.c
% touch A.vala
% make B.o    
touch A.vapi
echo "B.vala A.vapi B.vapi" >B.c
touch B.o
rm B.c
% make A.o
echo "A.vala A.vapi B.vapi" >A.c
touch A.o
rm A.c
% ls -lt
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel    0 19 Jul 00:11 A.o
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel    0 19 Jul 00:11 A.vapi
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel    0 19 Jul 00:11 B.o
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel    6 19 Jul 00:11 A.vala
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel    0 19 Jul 00:10 B.vapi
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel    6 19 Jul 00:10 B.vala
-rw-r--r--  1 norman  wheel  141 19 Jul 00:09 Makefile
%
```

Does that work?

Comment: This does not work for the reasons described in my original question, as well as in my comment to Jonathan. `.c`/`.vapi` files will not change their modification time if their contents do not change.